# firebase firestore adding new document inside a transaction - transaction.add is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I was assuming that it was possible to do something like:

```
transaction.add(collectionRef,{
  uid: userId,
  name: name,
  fsTimestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
});
```

But apparently it is not:

> transaction.add is not a function

The above message is displayed inside the chrome console.

I see that we can use the **set** method of the transaction to add a new document transactionally. see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

The thing is if I use **set** instead of add(which is not supported anyways), the id of the document should be created by me manually, firestore won't create it. 
see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Do you see any downside of this not having an add method that generates the id for you automatically?

For example, is it possible that the id generated by the firestore itself is somehow optimized considering various concerns including performance?

Which library/method do you use to create your document IDs in react-native while using transaction.set?

Thanks

Answer (score 53):

If you want to generate a unique ID for later use in creating a document in a transaction, all you have to do is use [CollectionReference.doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) with no parameters to generate a DocumentReference which you can set() later in a transaction.

(What you're proposing in your answer is way more work for the same effect.)

```
// Create a reference to a document that doesn't exist yet, it has a random id
const newDocRef = db.collection('coll').doc();

// Then, later in a transaction:
transaction.set(newDocRef, { ... });
```

Comment: By `db.collectionRef` you mean `db.collection`, right?

Comment: @DougStevenson hmm, when I try this I have an error: 

FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined. There were any updates?

Comment: Ok, As Can I see, it's not working with angularfire :/

Comment: @DougStevenson: does it mean that the doc id is then reserved? If so: is it needed to call doc() within the transaction? Or do we rely on the id generator to not statistically provide this value in another unrelated call?

Answer (score 6):

after some more digging I found in the source code of the firestore itself the below class/method for id generation:

```
export class AutoId {
  static newId(): string {
    // Alphanumeric characters
    const chars =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let autoId = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      autoId += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    }
    assert(autoId.length === 20, 'Invalid auto ID: ' + autoId);
    return autoId;
  }
}
```

see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/73a586c92afe3f39a844b2be86086fddb6877bb7/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L36

I extracted the method (except the assert statement) and put it inside a method in my code. Then I used the set method of the transaction as below:

```
generateFirestoreId(){
        const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        let autoId = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            autoId += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
        }
        //assert(autoId.length === 20, 'Invalid auto ID: ' + autoId);
        return autoId;
    }
```

then,

```
newDocRef = db.collection("PARENTCOLL").doc(PARENTDOCID).collection('SUBCOLL').doc(this.generateFirestoreId());
                        transaction.set(newDocRef,{
                            uid: userId,
                            name: name,
                            fsTimestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
                        });
```

Since I am using the same algo for the id generation as the firestore itself I feel better.

Hope this helps/guides someone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Doug Stevenson, this is how I got it worked with @angular/fire:

```
// Create a reference to a document and provide it a random id, e.g. by using uuidv4
const newDocRef = this.db.collection('coll').doc(uuidv4()).ref;

// In the transaction:
transaction.set(newDocRef, { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete Stefan's answer. For those using Angularfire, earlier to version 5.2 using CollectionReference.doc() results in an error "CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string".

This workaround worked for me:

```
const id = this.afs.createId();
const ref = this.afs.collection(this.collectionRef).doc(id);
transaction.set(ref, { ... });
```

Credit: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1974#issuecomment-448449448

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an answer solving the `id` problem. There's no need to generate your own `id`s. The `documentReference` is updated after the `transaction.set()` is called, so in order to access the Firestore's `id` you need to just do the following:

```
const docRef = collectionRef.doc();
const result = await transaction.set(docRef, input);
const id = docRef.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, firestore transaction object has 4 (get,set,update,delete) methods and doesnt has "add" method. However, the "set" method can be used instead.

```
import { collection,doc,runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";
```

On the other hand documentReference must be created for "set" method.

Steps :

1-) **collection** method create a collectionReference object.

```
const collectionRef = collection(FirebaseDb,"[colpath]");
```

2-) **doc** method create a documentReference object with unique random id for specified collectionReference.

```
const documentRef = doc(collectionRef);
```

3-) **add** operation can be performed with the transaction **set** method

```
try {
      await runTransaction(FirebaseDb,async (transaction) => {
                    

             await transaction.set(documentRef, {
                      uid: userId,
                      name: name,
                      fsTimestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
                    });
   
        })

 } catch (e) {
   console.error("Error : ", e);
 }
```