# How to obtain new document's ID from Firestore's transaction.set()?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit confused how to use .set() with a transaction and get new document's ID. I'd like to save a new document and use the ID later in the transaction. I'm following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674071/firebase-firestore-addding-new-document-inside-a-transaction-transaction-add-i?rq=1) how to add a document to the transaction.

```
const docRef = collectionRef.doc();
const result = await transaction.set(docRef, input);
```

Unfortunatelly, according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set) `transaction.set()` returns `transaction` instance, not an actual `documentSnapshot` like `transaction.get()` would, so `id` can not be obtained from the `result`. Docs also say that you're supposed to perform all reads first and then all writes, so I don't believe that any `set->get->set` combination is a proper solution (also you need a ref for the `get()` anyway).

Is there a way to obtain new document's ID inside a Firestore's transaction without generating your own IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the simplest answers are sometimes the least obvious.
It turns out that the `docRef` gets updated as a result of the `transaction.set()` and it contains the desired `id`. So to get `id` you just need to:

```
const docRef = collectionRef.doc();
const result = await transaction.set(docRef, input);
const id = docRef.id;
```

Comment: During my testing similarly constructed docRef has the id before and after transaction call.